# I've installed pyinputplus, but when I try to 'import pyinputplus' and run the code, I receive the ModuleNotFoundError. How can I fix this?

Tags: python, path, pip

I'm using Python 3.8 and Atom on Windows 10. I have two PATHs on the Environment Variable page. One PATH is `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts` and the other PATH is `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages.` I'm new to Python and frequently get the same error message whenever I install a new pip. Both selenium and pyinputplus give me an error.

Comment: are you trying to install it from command promt or from atom terminal?

Comment: From the command prompt. Do I need to put my project.py file in one of the folders on the PATH?

Comment: No. where did you install selenium from, from the command prompt or from atom terminal?

Comment: From the command prompt for both of them. If I type `pip list` into command prompt, then it even shows PyInputPlus and Selenium as installed.

Comment: so type "python" and enter then type "import PyInputPlus" and enter then see if you still get the same error..